# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when it is defined in the data?

Tags: vue.js

This is the data I see when I do this `{{user}}`

```
{ 
   "id":2,
   "name":"Instructor",
   "email":"instructor@gmail.com",
   "email_verified_at":null,
   "created_at":"2019-12-19 10:41:41",
   "updated_at":"2019-12-19 10:41:41",
   "uuid":"6f134dd0-227e-11ea-9d72-035d1b7f6efd",
   "last_name":"Prueba",
   "identification":"",
   "phone":"",
   "address":"",
   "user_type_id":2,
   "ranking":5,
   "user_type":{ 
      "id":2,
      "name":"Instructor"
   }
}
```

This is the part of the code where the error is occurring

```
<div class="resume">
    <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
        <star-rating v-model="user.ranking" :read-only="true" :star-size="15"
            :show-rating="false"></star-rating>
    <h4>{{ user.user_type.name }}</h4>
</div>
```

These are the errors

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

The error is on this line

> {{ user.user_type.name }}

This is the mounted and data for the vue file

```
data() {
    return {
        user: [],
    }
},
mounted() {
    if (this.$page.user) {
        this.user = this.$page.user;
    }
}
```

This is how the data is sent from the controller

```
if (Auth::user()->hasRole(2)) {
$user = Auth::user()->load('userType');
$courses = Course::all();
$locations = Location::all();
$notification = Notification::where('instructor_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->with('student', 'instructor', 'location', 'course')->get();
if (Auth::user()->rankings()->count() > 0) {
    $user->ranking = Auth::user()->rankings()->avg('ranking');
} else {
    $user->ranking = 5;
}

return Inertia::render('users/show')
    ->with([
        'user' => $user,
        'courses' => $courses,
        'locations' => $locations,
        'notification' => $notification
    ]);
}
```

Why is this error happening? The info is clearly there why does it say it's undefined?

Comment: Could you also show how that object is loaded into the component. And you are sure it's not `user.name` that's throwing the error?

Comment: @T.Short I know it's not the other line because the error message shows the line I said above only, and I'm not sure what you mean by the object loaded, you mean like in the data?

Comment: Could you share the code for the entire file where you have the Vue component

Comment: @T.Short it's almost 600 lines for the view where this is, I'll share the mounted and the data where it is defined

Comment: Also, show how the data is imported.

Comment: if you `console.log(this.$page.user)`. What does it show?

Comment: Why set `user` to an empty array? Of course if you try to reference '.name' on something undefined you'd get a type error (`[].user_type` is undefined)

Comment: @T.Short it shows basically the same thing (data wise) that I have in the beginning of the question.

Comment: @chazsolo I set it like that because it's an object and that's how I've always done it, how should I do instead?

Comment: Just upload it to https://hasteb.in

Comment: Try to set `user: null` in your data and add `<div class="resume" v-if="user">`. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: @fabruex yes that did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you load your data in asynchronous way, so when the template is mounted the `user` object is not available yet.

To prevent this just set `user: null` in your data, and then in your template:

`<div class="resume" v-if="user">`